# read python code from Github and execute locally

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a local python script that reads code from Github and executes it on my computer.

This will ensure that the latest version of code is always being used.

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bensharkey3/Guess-The-Number/master/Guess%20the%20number%20game.py) is the raw python code:

I have tried this, but doesn't work...

```
    with open(script) as file:
        data = file.read()

also

    exec(script)
```

I feel like this should be easily done but can't figure it out! Any help much appreciated

Comment: That's not how you should ensure that the latest version is ran. This is usually not a responsibility delegated to a Python script. Instead, write a `run` script which pulls from your master branch then executes the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the URL, you have the file reading and you have the execution. You're just missing the step where you download the file.

Easiest to use `urllib` in Python3:

```
import urllib.request

code = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bensharkey3/Guess-The-Number/master/Guess%20the%20number%20game.py'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(code)
data = response.read()

exec(data)
```

Note that relying on the URL is a pretty fragile way to ensure you have the latest code. Much better would be to use git to pull the latest, but this should at least get you started.